# After migrating .NET 4.6x to .NET Core 6. same code is producing "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed .net core migration."

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, migration, .net-4.6

After migrating our encryption project (library) from `.NET Framework 4.6x` to `.NET Core 6`, we are getting the error `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.`. The code is the same, with the same encryptions settings. The encryption is working in .NET Framework, it is not working in .NET Core.

All settings have been verified as the same, such as padding, the key, the initialization vector, etc..

Is the cyphered string being effected some by the new .NET Core CLR between the database and the library in a different way than the CLR in the .NET Framework 4.6?

What should we do differently to fix this issue?

This is legacy code we plan to eliminate, but we need to use it for now.

Old code:

```
using Previdence.Common.Security.Cryptography.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace DatabaseTableExport.Common.Security.Cryptography
{
    public class AESEncryption : IEncryptionProvider
    {
        private readonly byte[] _key;
        private readonly byte[] _iv;

        public AESEncryption(string key)
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            _key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            _iv = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        public string Encrypt(string value)
        {
            
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                if (encryptor != null)
                {
                    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(_key, _iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        value = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        public string Decrypt(string value)
        {
            
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                if (encryptor != null)
                {
                    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

    }
}

using System;

namespace Security_Legacy.Cryptography.Interfaces
{
    public interface IEncryptionProvider : IDisposable
    {
        string Decrypt(string cypheredText);
        string Encrypt(string plainText);
    }
}
```

New code:

```
using DatabaseTableExport.Services.Cryptography.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace DatabaseTableExport.Services.Cryptography
{
    public class AesEncryption : IEncryptionProvider
    {
        private readonly byte[] _key;
        private readonly byte[] _iv;

        public AesEncryption(string key)
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            _key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            _iv = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        public string Encrypt(string value)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                if (encryptor != null)
                {
                    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(_key, _iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        value = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
        public string Decrypt(string value)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                if (encryptor != null)
                {
                    encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                            value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            value = $"Failed to decrypt: {e.Message}";
                            var errorString = $"{e.Message}";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // nothing to dispose
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace Security_Legacy.Cryptography.Interfaces
{
    public interface IEncryptionProvider : IDisposable
    {
        string Decrypt(string cypheredText);
        string Encrypt(string plainText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the code works for me with .NET 6 (see here online for .NET 7: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vE94f1) and generates the same ciphertext as with .NET Framework 4.6.1 (see here online for .NET Framework 4.7.2: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MIAGoi) for identical passphrase and plaintext. Post sample data.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example. We have our database that has data in it that was encrypted with .NET 4.62 and now we need to decrypt that in .NET 6.  If use your dotnetfiddle example and replace the key with our key and the cyphered text with cyphered text from our database. The same "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed .net core migration." occurs. Usually that would mean we have a setting incorrect on the decryption, but the code is exactly the same. One idea we are working on is that there is a default setting in .NET 4.62 that is different in .NET 6.

Comment: Both codes (with .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.6.x) generate the same ciphertext for the same input data (passphrase, plaintext), which shows that the same default values are used in both environments (these are 1000 for the PBKDF2 iteration count, SHA-1 for the PBKDF2 digest, and CBC for the cipher mode; all other parameters, such as padding, have been specified). If the ciphertexts were really generated with the posted code, the decryption problem rather indicates that different passphrases were used for encryption and decryption.

Comment: @Topaco that is a good insight. The passphrase key is the same, copied straight from the web.config into the appsettings.json file. I have even verified it's the same passphrase key while stepping through in debug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the issue. Perhaps (non-productive) test data could shed some light on the matter, i.e. plaintext, passphrase and the ciphertext generated in your .NET Framework 4.6.x environment that raises the "padding is ivalid exception" in your .NET 6 environment.

Comment: @Topaco I appreciate your efforts. For security reason I can't provide the passphrase key and for privacy reasons I can't provide the data.

Comment: Well, I didn't say you should post the real data, but *non-productive* test data. If the problem is not caused by different passphrases (which you seem to assume) the problem should be reproducible in your environment with test data.

Comment: @Topaco after much more testing we have concluded that some of the data must of been created by a different encryption key that we no longer have access to. Thanks again for all you help. It was a great aid in confirming our findings and helping us arrive at this conclusion. If you want to create an answer that indicates this solution I will be glad to accept it.